# External font not showing on first page

Tags: css, wordpress, font-face

I've got a wordpress site that is using fontawesome icons for social media. The icons aren't showing on the first page, but show up on subsequent pages. I can't figure why they are not showing in the first instance. I am using wordpress enqueue function to load fonts. I've Inspected Element in Chrome > Resources > Frames and the fonts are loading before the style sheets, and font-awesome.min.css is loading before the theme css. Any ideas why the icons don't show on the first instance? here's a link http://www.achievebrowncounty.org/

Comment: You mean the social icons in the header?

Comment: The social icons in the header load for me on the home page.

Comment: @user3781632, same for me?

Comment: They aren't showing for me on the homepage - I just see white squares inside of the colored boxes. I took a look at the code and didn't notice any issues though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Home page http://www.achievebrowncounty.org/ is trying to load fonts from http://abc.arketypecreative.com and browser is simply refusing to do it as it is potentially unsafe operation. You can also notice browser notice in console log. Here is what you can find from console:

> Font from origin 'arketypecreative' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'achievebrowncounty' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: THANKS DENIS! That was it. I forgot to update the database to the new domain after moving from the dev server to live server. Duh.